# How to implement URL matching in WordPress like that?

Tags: wordpress

I want:

```
/blog
/blog/category-name
/blog/category-name/post-name
```

With this configuration, posts are not displayed.

[image]

How to implement this?

Comment: Wordpress installed in root?

Answer (score 0):

- You get 404 errors when you add "/blog/" to the custom permalink
  structure and then also add "/blog/" to the category base.  It should
  only be added to one, the custom permalink structure.
- If you leave your category base and tag base blank and just add
  "/blog/" to the front of the custom permalink structure to make it
  look like this "/blog/%postname% - this will get the desired result.
- Your pages will look like this: domain.com/pagename/ Your post URL
  will look like this: domain.com/blog/postname Your category URL will
  look like this - domain.com/blog/category/postname

**Implementation using plugin :**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalinks-customizer/